# Класс в качестве возвращаемого значения

Tags: c++

Впервые вижу подобную конструкцию:

```
class FirstClass
{
public:
    FirstClass(int a) : a(a) 
    {}
protected:
    int a;
};

class SecondClass
{
public:
    FirstClass foo()
    {

    }
};

int main()
{

    
    return 0;
}
```

Будет ли являться класс `FirstClass` вложенным при таком синтаксисе?

Для чего используется имя класса в качестве возвращаемого значения? Чтобы вернуть экземпляр?

Будет ли вызван конструктор `FirstClass` при вызове `foo`? Если да, то откуда возьмется значение?

Как вообще можно использовать это все? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример

Comment: Это учебное задание?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Нет. Нашел пример где-то в исходниках

Comment: такой вопрос не может  задавать только тот, кто вообще не открывает учебник

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для начала такая конструкция выдаст предупреждение:

```
<source>: In member function 'FirstClass SecondClass::foo()':
<source>: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
```

Ваша функция возвращает объект типа FirstClass по значению(by value)

```
FirstClass foo()
    {

    }
```

По коду не особо понятно что вы хотели сделать, возможно это?

```
FirstClass foo(int a)
    {
       return FirstClass(a);
    }
```

Comment: Я нашел данный код где-то в исходниках какого-то проекта, сам хочу понять, как это все работает :)

Comment: Ну без return это по идее неопределенное поведение, а так ,то что слева от названия функции это возвращаемое значение

Comment: Только, возвращаемый "тип", не значение.

Answer (score 2):

```
class SecondClass
{
public:
    FirstClass foo()
    {

    }
};
```

Это всего лишь функция `foo()` в классе `SecondClass`, которая должна возвращать объект `FirstClass`. Но по факту, этого не делает. Но если бы делала (с соответствующим `return`), то раз есть объект — то обязательно есть и его конструктор.

Comment: То есть, при вызове `foo` будет вызван конструктор? А как тогда указать в нем аргументы?

Comment: Как вы захотите. Вы должны вернуть объект `FirstClass`, а как именно вы его создаете — это ваше дело. Может, вы будете вызывать еще какую-то фабричную функцию, которая его создает. Может, будете строить ее исходя из какой-то арифметики и введенных данных.  Вариантов уйма. Главное - что у `FirstClass` есть только один конструктор от `int`, так что этот `int` хочешь-не хочешь, а где-то будет указан. Может, вами явно, может, где-то в каком-то чужом коде. Обсуждение сферического коня в вакууме особого смысла не имеет... Приведенный вами код компилироваться не будет, так что говорить не о чем.